# Analysing data in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have built a database in mongodb powered by mongolabs. At this moment I have 3
columns - username, book borrowed and date borrowed for each week of the year. Therefore, 1 username can borrow different books on different dates.  I am currently using pymongo to analyse the data. I want to get all the books borrowed by a username in that week and display it as a list. How to do this cause been stuck on this for a week?

Current database:

```
  { Username: A,
     Book_Borrowed: XYZ,
     Date: 11/2/10 
   } 
   { Username: B,
     Book_Borrowed: FGH,
     Date: 12/2/10 
   }  
   { Username: A,
     Book_Borrowed: DWW,
     Date: 13/2/10 
   } 
   { Username: A,
     Book_Borrowed: GGG,
     Date: 14/2/10 
   } 
   { Username: B,
     Book_Borrowed: DKD,
     Date: 14/2/10 
   }  
   { Username: C,
     Book_Borrowed: DWW,
     Date: 12/2/10 
   }
```

Desired output:

```
A: [XYZ,DWW,GGG]
B: [FGH,DKD] 
C: [DWW]
```

Comment: You need to `$group` by "Username" and `$push` the "Book_Borrowed" field.

Comment: @Styvane could you give a pseudocode or like an example in pymongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{"$group": {"_id": "$username", "Booksborrowed": {"$push": "$Book_Borrowed"}}}
)
```